# How do you add thumbnails to an embed message in DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I have been bashing my head against the wall for 8 hours now, trying to figure out how to add thumbnails to embeded messages. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gQZc0jlPq4) that uses ThumbnailURL, something that doesn't exist in the context he's using it for. Instead I just have Thumbnail which does not take a string, but rather an EmbedThumbnail which I can't access at all.

```
var avatarEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
        {
            Title = "Enter the game.",
            Thumbnail = ctx.Client.CurrentUser.AvatarUrl,
            Color = DiscordColor.Azure,


        };
```

Please don't send links to docs and tutorials. I've tried. I've really tried. But this just seems like an issue that is very recent and therefore resources on it would be next to none. Also the docs don't seem to have example code, making it all more frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your version but I use the latest nightly build.
and I do it like this

```
            var builder = new DiscordEmbedBuilder 
            {
                Title = "Title Here",
                Color = DiscordColor.Azure
            };
            builder.WithThumbnail(ctx.Client.CurrentUser.AvatarUrl);
```

but you can also do it this way

```
            var builder = new DiscordEmbedBuilder 
            {
                Title = "Title Here",
                Color = DiscordColor.Azure,
                Thumbnail = new DiscordEmbedBuilder.EmbedThumbnail
                {
                    Url = ctx.Client.CurrentUser.AvatarUrl
                } 
            };
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using the latest version and this worked. Still don't know why they changed it to that.

Comment: @AFish I not sure why they changed it, but it more than likely is because you can also fill in a optional height and width for it, so `ThumbnailUrl` to `Thumbnail` thats just my guess.